# proving a function is Borelmeasurable

Tags: real-analysis, borel-sets

Suppose we have
$$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x-y}\right) \qquad x>y \\ x^2+y^2 \qquad x \leq y \end{cases}.$$

How does one show that this is is a Borelmeasurable function?

I thought by using the fact that if a function is continuous on an open or measurable domain, it is measurable, but I wasn't able to get down the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Given a measurable space $(X,\mathscr A)$, $A \in \mathscr A$, and $f,g \colon X \to \mathbb R$ two measurable functions (that is, for any Borel subset of $\mathbb R$, its preimage is an element of $\mathscr A$), then $h \colon X \to \mathbb R$ defined by $$\forall x \in X, \quad h(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x) & \textrm{if $x \in A$} \\
g(x) & \textrm{if $x \notin A$}
\end{cases}$$ is also measurable. This is true because $A \in \mathscr A$ implies that the characteristic functions $\chi_A$ and $\chi_{X \setminus A}$ are measurable, and because the sum and product of measurable functions is again measurable, it follows that $h = f \chi_A + g\chi_{X \setminus A}$ is measurable.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by the characteristic functions?

Comment: @Geigercounter Sure. I mean that, for $E \subseteq X$, the function $\chi_E \colon X \to \mathbb R$ is defined by $$\forall x \in X, \quad \chi_E(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if $x \in E$,} \\ 0 & \textrm{if $x \notin E$.} \end{cases}$$